# i have a json file with a key label and i want to read its value based on localization

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, properties-file

Below is the code mentioned in JSON file.I need to return this JSON to UI but the label values should be replaced with propperties file equivalent key-value based on it local value.what is the best way to read the value of label from properties file based on localization.

```
               {
                "id": "org",
               "label": "menu.orgnazation.label",
               "newColumn": null
                 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Resource Bundles. Resource Bundle properties file can help you to achieve localization.

Reference :

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-internationalization.html

https://www.baeldung.com/java-resourcebundle